# C# OpenXML- Copying charts from Word document to another Word docu

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

Im trying to copy charts from one word document to another, and placing them at a bookmark location using OpenXml. However im unsure of how to append or insert the copied chart to the bookmark. I believe i have to add the chart object to a drawing or another object before adding it to the paragraph, but im having trouble getting this to work. Code below is the base of what im using to test with:

```
  using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(SourceDoc, false))
        {
            List<ChartPart> chartFind = doc.MainDocumentPart.ChartParts.ToList();
            using (WordprocessingDocument copydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {

                MainDocumentPart mainPart = copydoc.MainDocumentPart;
                Body body = mainPart.Document.GetFirstChild<Body>();
                var bmStart = body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>();
                var bmEnd = body.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>();
                //phone calls Chart
                ChartPart PhoneChart = chartFind[0];
                ChartPart chartPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
                chartPart.ChartSpace = (ChartSpace)PhoneChart.ChartSpace.Clone();

                foreach (BookmarkStart bookMarkStart in bmStart)
                {

                    if (bookMarkStart.Name == "test")
                    {

                        var id = bookMarkStart.Id.Value;
                        var bookmarkEnd = bmEnd.Where(b => b.Id.Value == id).First();
                        Paragraph chartPara = new Paragraph();
                        bookmarkEnd.Parent.InsertAfterSelf(chartPara);
                        chartPara.InsertAfterSelf(chartPart.ChartSpace);


                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Charts are additional xml parts in the docx zip package. It's not possible to simply "copy/paste": relationships are required. I recommend you start by 1) open the sample document you're working with and copy/paste that chart as you want your code to do, to the bookmark. 2) save this as a NEW file name and close...

Comment: ...3) Open the original document in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. Take a moment to look at the underlying xml files and the document's BODY in particular, where the chart is. Now use the "Compare" function to bring in the second file. Look at the code generated to turn the first into the second. That will give you an idea of how to approach inserting and linking in the new chart.

Answer (score 0):

Open XML SDK Productivity Tool was a big help in troubleshooting. I was able add a chart by:

1. Creating a ChartPart object
2. Clone the original charts ChartSpace and add it to my ChartPart
3. Create a Drawing object with a ChartReference with the same ID as my ChartPart in order 
   to link them
4. Appending the Drawing object to new run and paragraph before inserting at the bookmark

I did have an issue that wasted a bit of time, which was caused by the data in the charts being linked to an excel document, which i wasnt able to access through my app. In order to display the charts i had to break the external data relationship through:
 `chartPart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/ 
 relationships/oleObject", new System.Uri("NULL", System.UriKind.Relative), "rId2");`

the code below for future reference

```
        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(SourceDoc, false))
        {


            //List<ChartPart> chartFind = doc.MainDocumentPart.ChartParts.ToList();
            //List<Drawing> drawingList = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Drawing>().ToList();

            MainDocumentPart mainPartDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart;

            var mainDoc = mainPartDoc.Document;



            using (WordprocessingDocument copydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {


                MainDocumentPart mainPart = copydoc.MainDocumentPart;
                var document = mainPart.Document;
                var bmStart = document.Descendants<BookmarkStart>();
                var bmEnd = document.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>();

                foreach (BookmarkStart bookMarkStart in bmStart)

                {


                    if (bookMarkStart.Name == "test")
                    {
                        //find charts and names from original document
                        List<ChartPart> findCharts = mainPartDoc.ChartParts.ToList();
                        var partCheck = (from f in findCharts
                                         select f.ChartSpace.GetFirstChild<Chart>().Title.InnerText).ToList();



                        ChartPart chartPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();

                        ChartPart chartSelect = findCharts[3];
                        //ChartPart chartSelect = mainPartDoc.ChartParts.FirstOrDefault();


                        chartPart.ChartSpace = (ChartSpace)chartSelect.ChartSpace.Clone();


                        string relId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart);


                        AutoUpdate autoUpdate1 = new AutoUpdate() { Val = false };

                        chartPart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/oleObject", 
                            new System.Uri("NULL", System.UriKind.Relative), "rId2");

                        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();


                        Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
                        Run run = new Run();

                        Inline inline = new Inline() { DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U, AnchorId = "716A168E", EditId = "2D11B07F" };

                        Extent extent = new Extent() { Cx = 6572250L, Cy = 2586038L };

                        EffectExtent effectExtent1 = new EffectExtent() { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 5080L };

                        DocProperties docProperties1 = new DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)13U, Name = "Chart 13" };

                        NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1 = new NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties();

                        dr.Graphic graphic = new dr.Graphic();
                        graphic.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

                        dr.GraphicData graphicData = new dr.GraphicData() { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" };

                        ChartReference chartReference1 = new ChartReference() { Id = relId };
                        chartReference1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
                        chartReference1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");

                        graphicData.Append(chartReference1);
                        graphic.Append(graphicData);
                        inline.Append(extent);
                        inline.Append(effectExtent1);
                        inline.Append(docProperties1);
                        inline.Append(nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1);
                        inline.Append(graphic);
                        drawing.Append(inline);
                        run.Append(drawing);
                        paragraph.Append(run);

                        var id = bookMarkStart.Id.Value;
                        var bookmarkEnd = bmEnd.Where(i => i.Id.Value == id).First();

                        bookmarkEnd.Parent.InsertAfterSelf(paragraph);

                        // mainPart.Document.Body.Append(paragraph);
                    }


                }


            }
```